# Сохранение данных счётчика при перезагрузке страницы (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Есть кнопка которая при нажатии добавляет +1 к каунтеру. Задача сделать так, чтобы на каждом устройстве данные сохранялись при перезагрузке страницы.
Код самой кнопки:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks = +clicks + 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  updateStorage(clicks);
};

function onReset() {
  if (confirm('Вы уверенны? Данные обнулятся!')) {
    clicks = 0;
    updateStorage(clicks);
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }
}

function updateStorage(clicks) {
  localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem localStorage.getItem`

Comment: Можно пожалуйста в рамках моего примера, я не понимаю как это применить, как не пытался - не сохраняется.

Answer (score 2):

https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/zQQGYV?editors=1010

```js
let i, update = c => localStorage.setItem('counter', count.textContent = i = c)
clear.onclick = e => update(0)
inc.onclick = e => update(i+1)
update(localStorage.getItem('counter') || 0)
```

```html
<span id="count"></span>
<button id="inc">inc</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но мне необходимо чтобы число записывалось не в рамках кнопки, а отдельно. Сейчас уже почти всё работает, кроме того, что при обновлении страницы значение становится 0, но при новом нажатии кнопки оно продолжается с последного значения. Не могу побороть. Обновил актуальный код в первом посте

Comment: используйте вместо textcontent переменную

Comment: для меня это всё совсем в новинку, так что я не особо понимаю где и как :) Потому и прошу готовое решение в рамках того, что я написал в первом посте. Если вас конечно не затруднит.

Answer (score -1):

Итоговый вариант, вдруг кому-то понадобится. Большое спасибо за помощь!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 0;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 0; });
function onClick() {
  clicks = +clicks + 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  updateStorage(clicks);
};

function onReset() {
  if (confirm('Вы уверенны? Данные обнулятся!')) {
    clicks = 0;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    updateStorage(clicks);
  }
}

function updateStorage(clicks) {
  localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks);
}
</script>
```